# How i can connect orin nx to pixhawk and then to intel d455

Tags: intellisense, ros, nvidia-jetson, dronekit, mavlink

Hello im having trouble connecting **pixhawk to orange cube** with **orin nx** and then to **intel d455**.

I dont know if i have to install all those packages from that website :

https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/companion-computer-nvidia-tx2.html

Jetpack is already installed and also the steps are not so analytic of how and what to do.

Iv also tried this article : Connecting PixHawk to Raspberry Pi and NVIDIA Jetson - Hackster.io

I used pip3 but the mavlink send me crypto kind of staff .Also i then try to open mission planner but i cant connect my drone to my baord with this software.

Im kinda confused of what software - firmware i need there are so many.Mavlink protocol , mavros,ros .

Can anyone tell me how i can connect all of this and what steps i need to follow?

Thanks.